# Coffee Gulp File Not Writing To destination Folder On Watch Task

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gulp, gulp-watch

I am creating a ghost (http://ghost.io) theme and placed the directory in `C:/www/megane_theme` and my destination folder is in `C:/www/megane.local/contents/theme/megane` The thing is, when I run the gulp individually, it writes to the destination folder just fine. But when it is watching any changes, it responds to the changes (console notif showing the task ran) but the destination file is not written.

Just to clarify why is my source file is so far from the destination file, it seems that the bower from ghost is being prioritized when I type `bower install` and even if I explicitly type `bower install bower.json` in the source directory inside the ghost folder. So as not to have that problem, I moved it away from the ghost folder and have its own folder.

Here is the gulpfile for reference.

https://gist.github.com/abarcenas29/88bcd0dd00d3aa941924

Comment: If you try to specify different targetPath for each task, does it work ?

Comment: @clemkoa You mean have line 24 in the code be written to all of the task instead of globally referencing it?

Answer (score 0):

In gulp tasks You overwrite the `targetPath`.

After first run of task `sass` global variable `targetPath` have new value: `/www/megane.local/content/themes/megane/assets/css`.

Next task: `angular`. Global variable `targetPath` have value `/www/megane.local/content/themes/megane/assets/css/assets/js`.

The solution is simple: don't overwrite global variable `targetPath`

```
...

gulp.task "sass", ->
  sourcePath = "styles/template/**/*.sass"
  sass(sourcePath,{sourcemap:true})
    .pipe(plumber())
    .on('error',sass.logError)
    .pipe(prefixer())
    .pipe(minfiyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join targetPath,"assets","css"))

...

gulp.task "angular", ->
  sourcePath = [
    "angular/config/*.coffee"
    "angular/services/**/*.coffee"
    "angular/directives/**/*.coffee"
    "angular/controllers/**/*.coffee"
  ]
  gulp.src(sourcePath)
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(coffee {bare:true})
      .pipe(ngAnnotate {single_quotes:true})
      .pipe(sourcemap.init {loadMaps: true})
      .pipe(concat 'angular.min.js')
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(sourcemap.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest path.join targetPath,"assets","js")

...
```